# Dynamic Columns Selection in SUMMARIZECOLUMNS

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to dynamically select columns in `summarizecolumns` based on a condition:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    IF( True(), Date[Year], Date[FiscalYear]),
    "Reference Date", STARTOFMONTH(Date[Date])
)
```

For a dataset like

```
Date, Year, FiscalYear
2005-01-01, 2005, 2004/2005
2005-01-02, 2005, 2004/2005
```

Already tried workarounds like using `DEFINE VAR`, `DISTINCT SELECTCOLUMNS`, or wrapping the columns with `ALL`, but I just can't work it out.

Any ideas how it might work?

Answer (score 0):

The simple but ugly approach is to do this:

```
IF (
    TRUE (),
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( Date[Year], "Reference Date", STARTOFMONTH ( Date[Date] ) ),
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( Date[FiscalYear], "Reference Date", STARTOFMONTH ( Date[Date] ) )
)
```

I can't think of a way to do this without code duplication at the moment.